# delete file other than particular extension file format

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have a lot of different type of files in one folder. i need to delete the files but except the pdf file. 
I tried to display the pdf file only. but i need to delete the other than pdf files

```
ls -1 | xargs file | grep 'PDF document,' | sed 's/:.*//'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls |xargs file|awk -F":" '!($2~/PDF document/){print $1}'|xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Why rm -rf? Mr Black probably didn't want a version which nukes all his subdirectories :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following - I've used `echo rm` instead of `rm` for safety:

```
for i in *
do
    [ x"$(file --mime-type -b "$i")" != xapplication/pdf ] && echo rm "$i"
done
```

The `--mime-type -b` options to file make the output of file easier to deal with in a script.

Comment: when i try the above code, it shows the following error.

file: unrecognized option `--mime-type'
Usage: file [-bcikLhnNrsvz0] [-e test] [-f namefile] [-F separator] [-m magicfiles] file...
       file -C -m magicfiles
Try `file --help' for more information.

Comment: Which version of `file` do you have?  (You can find it with `file --version`.)

Comment: OK, that's quite an old version now.  Anyway, it sounds as if your problem is sorted regardless.

Answer (score 2):

$ ls
aa.txt  a.pdf  bb.cpp  b.pdf

$ ls | grep -v .pdf | xargs rm -rf

$ ls
a.pdf  b.pdf

:) !

Answer (score 0):

Try inverting the grep match:

```
ls -1 | xargs file | grep -v 'PDF document,' | sed 's/:.*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's rare in my experience to encounter PDF files which don't have a .pdf extension. You don't state why "file" is necessary in the example, but I'd write this as:

```
# find . -not -name '*.pdf' -delete
```

Note that this will recurse into subdirectories; use "-maxdepth 1" to limit to the current directory only.

Comment: Yes Phil, I accepted you thoughts. But, you could know one thing, i have big processed with some other servers and data centers. So, sometimes, some error occurred in myway.May be session time problem etc, etc.. We can't predict with it. So, html file content saved as pdf with the extension of pdf, that's why i'm asking about this question. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.